# Can't use image thumbnail from live stream(m3u8) in collectionView Swift 4

Tags: stream, live, m3u8, avassetimagegenerator

It's part of my code (written in Swift 4, xcode 9.2), where I want to do that.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "customCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionViewCell
if let thumbnailImage = getThumbnailImage(forUrl: str!) {
        cell.imageView.image = thumbnailImage
    }
    cell.nameLabel.text = devices[indexPath.row].name.capitalized
    print(devices[indexPath.row].url)
    return cell
}
```

and getThumnailImage function

```
func getThumbnailImage(forUrl url: URL) -> UIImage? {
    let asset: AVAsset = AVAsset(url: url)
    let imageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
    do {
        let thumbnailImage = try imageGenerator.copyCGImage(at: CMTimeMake(1, 60) , actualTime: nil)
        return UIImage(cgImage: thumbnailImage)
    } catch let error {
        print(error)
    }
    return nil
}
```

When I run it, I get this error:

> Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11850 "Operation Stopped" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The server is not correctly configured., NSLocalizedDescription=Operation Stopped, NSUnderlyingError=0x61c00044fbd0 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12939 "(null)"}}

Comment: have you found answer for this??

Comment: No. I can get thumbnail for .mp4 format, in .m3u8 can't.